# SQL Cross Apply Select with Table-Valued Function Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have the following query and receive the error when I check syntax.  I don't see what's wrong.  The parameter and field are the same data type.

```
select
    p.ID
from dbo.PART as p
cross apply dbo.FN_SEC_BOM_Listing(p.ID) as bl
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
> Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: Having definitions for dbo.PART and dbo.FN_SEC_BOM_Listing(x), at least partially, would help. Sample SQL that can be run would also help.

Comment: Not enough information.  As it stands, the syntax is fine.  The error is not coming from line 4 of the code above.  As @pmbAustin says, you need to provide definitions of your objects.  Just to be sure, I created my own definitions and there are no syntax errors showing.

Comment: Okay, here is the additional information.

Comment: Okay, here is the additional information.
 
 Table:
 dbo.Part
  ROWID (int, not null)
  ID (PK, varchar(30), not null)

 Function:
 ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_SEC_BOM_Listing] (@PPart varchar(30))
 RETURNS TABLE
 AS
 RETURN
 (
  WITH BOMMaterial (SortKey, Hiearchy, ParentPart, ParentDesc, ParentQty, BaseID, LotID, SplitID, SubID, Type, OpSeq, MtlSeq, MtlPart, QtyPer, QtyNeeded, Level)

Comment: We are running SQL Server 2008 r2

Comment: select
        p.ID,
     bl.*
    from dbo.PART as p
     cross apply dbo.FN_SEC_BOM_Listing ('2475M44G01') as bl
    where p.ID = '2475M44G01'

Comment: The above query returns data.